# Is it necessary that "img" should be used as block elements in CSS (display:block;)

Tags: css, display

Because I have read that it is efficient to use img as block elements for scaling purposes.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it isn't "necessary"... It probably is easier to use it as `display: block;` for scaling purposes, though.

```css
.cats{display: inline;}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg" class="cats">
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Images will scale without being `block` as long as they have a relative width or `max-width` assigned.

Using `width` will size the `img` relative to the parent's size.

Using `max-width: 100%` will cause the image to be it's native size as long as the parent is wider, but as soon as the parent's width becomes less than the `img` width, the `img` will scale with the width of the parent.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg">
</div>
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg">
</div>
```